# pasar consulta de MYSQL A JPQL?

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql

mi consulta es la siguiente tengo la siguiente consulta en MYSQL

```
 SELECT `producto`.`NOMBRE` NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, `ordentrabajo_producto`.`CANTIDAD` CANTIDAD, `cliente`.`NOMBRE` NOMBRE_CLIENTE
 FROM `ordentrabajo_producto`
 INNER JOIN `ordentrabajo` 
 ON `ordentrabajo_producto`.`ID_ORDENTRABAJO` = `ordentrabajo`.`ID`
 INNER JOIN `producto`
 ON `ordentrabajo_producto`.`ID_PRODUCTO` = `producto`.`ID`
 INNER JOIN `cliente`
 ON `ordentrabajo`.`ID_CLIENTE` = `cliente`.`ID`
 WHERE `ordentrabajo`.`FECHA_ORDEN_TRABAJO` BETWEEN ('2017-09-01 00:00:00') AND ('2017-09-30 00:00:00');
```

y la quiero pasar a lenguaje JPQL de la siguiente forma

```
OrdentrabajoProducto o INNER JOIN Ordentrabajo  ot ON o.idOrdentrabajo =    ot.id INNER JOIN Producto p ON o.idProducto = p.id INNER JOIN Cliente c ON ot.idCliente = c.id WHERE ot.fechaOrdenTrabajo BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

Pero me genera un null la querer mostrar una lista con la consulta

> Información:   ERROR:
>
> Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
>
> Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

metodo

```
  public void listenerBotonBuscarProductoPorFecha(){

    if (capturarFechaDesde != null && capturarFechaHasta != null) {
        String namedQuery = "OrdentrabajoProducto.findByRangoFechas";
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("startDate", capturarFechaDesde);
        parametros.put("endDate", capturarFechaHasta);
        ordenTrabajoProductoListFecha = ordentrabajoProductoFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery, parametros);
    } else {
        lanzarMensajeError("Debe Ingresar un Rango de Fechas de Orden de Trabajo");
    }


}
```

Comment: Pon el método donde mandas a llamar tu JPQL en el createQuery seguramente algún parámetro que le estas enviando va nulo

Comment: Listo ya lo edite